# Is there a way to pass custom parameters in truffle command line?

Tags: contract-development, truffle-migration

I am having 3 different environments:

- dev
- test
- live

I have one contract deployed on three different addresses, that I want to use based on environment, since for every environment we will store different data into smart contract.

I am using teamcity for CI, but I am interested how to differentiate environment with Truffle migrations, so based on environment to pick different address from inside of migration?

Example:
Assume I have migration file:

```
    const test = artifacts.require("./test")


    module.exports = function(deployer, custom_argument_that_i_can_pass_via_teamcity) {

console.log(custom_argument_that_i_can_pass_via_teamcity);
        deployer
            .deploy(test);
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration) addresses your issue:

> Your configuration file is called truffle.js and is located at the
>   root of your project directory. This file is a Javascript file and can
>   execute any code necessary to create your configuration. It must
>   export an object representing your project configuration like the
>   example below.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

There you add your different environment configurations.

Below in the doc, it says how to send the env to use to truffle:

```
truffle migrate --network live
```

**Update**:

I think I understand your question better now that you've added more details to it.

You have access to the `process.argv` global variable inside migration files, so you can use [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) to parse it and extract your `custom_param` from it:

```
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2), {string: ['custom_argument']});

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  console.log("----migration custom argument: ",argv['custom_argument']);
  ......
};
```

And then executing `truffle migrate --custom_argument "hello beautiful world"`

prints `----migration custom argument:  hello beautiful world`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated answer, that's not what I needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer also :)